# Changing ContourStyle based on an inequality

Tags: plotting, conditional

I would like to create a bifurcation diagram with `ContourPlot`. Suppose I want to plot the contour `1-2*a*Q+3*Q^3==0` with `a` the x-axis, `Q` the y-axis. I also want linestyle/thickness of the contour plot to change depending on the expression `expr = 9*Q^2-2*a`. If `expr>0`, I want it to be dashed; if `expr<0`, I want it to be a thick line. How to accomplish this?

Some previous posts about similar topic suggested putting an `If` statement inside the plot, but when I try something like

```
ContourPlot[If[expr>0, 1-2*a*Q+3*Q^3 == 0], {a,-2,2}, {Q,-2,2}]
```

it gives error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create two contour plots, and show them together:

```
Show[
    ContourPlot[
        1-2*a*Q+3*Q^3==0, {a,-2,2}, {Q,-2,2},
        RegionFunction->Function[{a,Q},9Q^2-2a<0],
        ContourStyle->Thick
    ],
    ContourPlot[
        1-2*a*Q+3*Q^3==0, {a,-2,2}, {Q,-2,2},
        RegionFunction->Function[{a,Q},9Q^2-2a>0],
        ContourStyle->Dashed
    ]
]
```

[image]

Another possibility using a single contour plot:

```
ContourPlot[
    {
    ConditionalExpression[
        1-2 a Q+3 Q^3,
        9Q^2-2a<0
    ]==0,
    ConditionalExpression[
        1-2 a Q+3 Q^3,
        9Q^2-2a>0
    ]==0
    },
    {a,-2,2},
    {Q,-2,2},
    ContourStyle->{Thick,Dashed}
]
```

Comment: That solves my problem. But when I handle more complicated equations I want to define `bifurEq=1-2*a*Q+3*Q^3`. So in the `RegionFunction` I need to have something like `Function[{a,Q},D[bifurEq,Q]>0]`, but then it gives me error saying that blah blah blah must be a Boolean function. How to fix this (have Mathematica do the algebra instead of me typing the equation myself)?

Comment: Try `Function[{a, Q}, Evaluate @ D[bifurEq, Q] > 0]` instead.

Comment: It works. Thank you.